# Azure Purview - How to extract schema output after the scan?

Tags: azure, azure-purview

Is it possible to extract the schema after scanning an asset in Purview?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by cycling through the referredEntities.

**Example:** Get the entity information for an Azure SQL Table by using the command - `pv entity read --guid "AZURE_SQL_TABLE_GUID"`

Within the JSON response, there are referredEntities, which includes the Azure SQL Columns and their classifications (if applicable).

[image]

> Working example for ADLS resource set using purview cli with PowerShell:

[image]

**Code Sample:**

```
 $env:PURVIEW_NAME = "YOUR_PURVIEW_ACCOUNT_NAME"
 $guid = "YOUR_ADLS_GEN2_RESOURCE_SET_GUID"
 $adls_resource_set = pv entity read --guid $guid | ConvertFrom-Json
 $tabular_schema_guid = $adls_resource_set.entity.relationshipAttributes.tabular_schema.guid
 $tabular_schema = pv entity read --guid $tabular_schema_guid | ConvertFrom-Json
 ForEach ($x in $tabular_schema.referredEntities.PSObject.Properties) {$x.Value.classifications.typeName}
```